# Задача на замену символов

Tags: алгоритм, c

Имеется вот такая задача:

> "В строке вместо пробелов вставить запятую и пробел."

Как её решить? Я думаю с помощью строк. Но передумал. Наставьте на путь истинный.

Comment: Тут еще надо для себя решить: каждый пробел (в т.ч. одиночный) заменяем на ", " или группу пробелов на ", " или как-то еще.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, как уже написали, в С нет стандартной функции для замены подстрок. Но ее несложно написать самому. Вот, например, мой говнокод:

```
char* replace_substring(const char *source, const char *substring, const char *replace_with)
{
    size_t substring_s    = strlen(substring);
    size_t replace_with_s = strlen(replace_with);
    size_t source_s       = strlen(source);

    char *result = malloc(source_s + 1);
    char *ptr = result;
    if(!ptr) return 0;

    while(*source) {
        /* Копируем исходную строку до тех пор, пока не встретим нужную подстроку */
        if (strncmp(source, substring, substring_s)) {
            *ptr++ = *source++;
        } else {
            ptr  -= (int)result;
            /* Меняем размер новой строки (так как $substring и 
               $replace_with - не всегда будут одиноковы по длине) */
            result = realloc(result, source_s += (replace_with_s - substring_s));
            /* Копируем $replace_with в новую строку */
            ptr  += strlen(strcpy(ptr = result + (int)ptr, replace_with));
            /* Следующий проход цикла начнем уже со следующего 
               за найденной подстрокой символа */
            source  += substring_s;
        }  
    }
    *ptr = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек, а то слишком быстро учебная программа идет. Просто напросто не успею лабы сдавать(((

Comment: Делая realloc() в **этой** задаче внутри цикла, Вы хотите экономить память ? Боюсь разочаровать, но реально (без потоков и обработчиков сигналов, которые параллельно претендуют на память) не получится. 

Надо вычислить максимально возможную длину результата (исходя из разности длин образца и замены), сделать malloc(), в цикле сформировать результат, а в конце сделать realloc(), вернув излишек.

1). Быстрее. 

2) Памяти у системы запросим не больше (а скорее меньше).

Comment: @avp спасибо за совет, учту.